# KnpPaginator loading only 50 results out of 300 elements for each page

Tags: symfony, request

I have a query that search for all elements and display them with a paginator.
And I have a controller where I make KnpPaginator works.

When I load my pages, it load all 300 elements and after slice them in 10 for each page.

How can I actually load 50 by 50 only without loading all and have them in order in my pagination?

**My controller**

```
    private function resultsAction(User $user, $type, $archive, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   // $results = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->setQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

    $dql = "SELECT opn FROM STuserBundle:Operation opn";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    /**
     * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
     */
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $results = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $request->query->getInt('page',1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit',50)
    );

    return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
}
```

**The query**

```
public function findByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
                ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
                ->setParameter("type", $type)
                ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
                ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
                ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
                ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
                ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

So I can maybe create a new query for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the query. I would suggest build the query and feed it to `KNPPaginatorBundle` to further manipulation for pagination. Hence, your repository becomes :

```
public function findByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
                ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
                ->setParameter("type", $type)
                ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
                ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
                ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
                ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
                ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
    ;
    return $qb;
}
```

This way, KNP can handle the pagination through query, and it won't be heavy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification, I see it better now :) How can i after let knp handle it? in the controller?

Comment: Nothing different needed. You are doing fine there. Just test it out.

Comment: I don't know if its actually working because I don't get anything in the profiler. i guess its the same amount of time. On Knp documentation I saw they did something like this `$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);` in the controller directly

Comment: This is same. A `DQL` and `Query Builder` is same. They don't execute. I have tested this before I implemented in several projects. With a total of 300 results, you hardly can see a difference.